# How do I use IAuthorizationService in MVC 5 (.Net Framework) for authorizing my token from IdentityServer 4

Tags: authorization, identityserver4, asp.net-mvc-5

We used IAuthorizationService (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization) in .Net core for authorizing access token comming from Idntity Server 4. Is it possible to use IAuthorizationService in MVC 5 for authorizing same token. If yes, what is the procedure to bootstrap IAuthorizationService in MVC 5 or not what will be the best approach ?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably talking about the ASP.NET Core authorization framework

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction

This is just a general purpose framework and has nothing to do with access tokens. You'd still need some sort of library to validate the incoming token (e.g. middleware).

That said - the authorization library has been back-ported to MVC5/Web API2 here:

https://github.com/DavidParks8/Owin-Authorization

Comment: Thanks. I am searching for something like resource based authorization  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased) in my mvc5 app,  which was newly introduced in .net core but not policy based.

Comment: As I said - the repo I pointed you to is the back-port of that.